# TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable python to html

Tags: html, python-3.x, iterable

I'm trying to fill a html table with a dictionary I've generated from a API of professional sports scores and schedules. Below is a sample of the python and html I'm using a sample output from `today_games()`.

```
rows = today_games()
    return render_template("games.html", rows=rows)


 <table class="table table-striped">
  <tr>
    <th>Game</th>
    <th>Time</th>
    <th>Away</th>
    <th>Home</th>
    <th>League</th>
  </tr>
  {%for row in rows%}
  <tr>
    <td>{{row.GameDate}}</td>
    <td>{{row.GameTime}}</td>
    <td>{{row.AwayTeamAbbr}}</td>
    <td>{{row.HomeTeamAbbr}}</td>
    <td>{{row.League}}</td>
  </tr>
  {%endfor%}
</table>
{% endblock %}
```

Here is a sample of the output from today_games():

```
[{
    'HomeTeamCity': 'Minnesota',
    'Date/TimeofUpdate:2017-05-075:13:51PM': '',
    'HomeTeamName': 'Twins',
    'HomeTeamID': '120',
    'AwayTeamName': 'Red Sox',
    'AwayTeamAbbr': 'BOS',
    'GameTime': '2:10PM',
    'AwayTeamCity': 'Boston',
    'HomeTeamAbbr': 'MIN',
    'GameDate': '2017-05-07',
    'AwayTeamID': '113'
}, {
    'HomeTeamCity': 'Milwaukee',
    'Date/TimeofUpdate:2017-05-075:13:51PM': '',
    'HomeTeamName': 'Brewers',
    'HomeTeamID': '134',
    'AwayTeamName': 'Red Sox',
    'AwayTeamAbbr': 'BOS',
    'GameTime': '7:40PM',
    'AwayTeamCity': 'Boston',
    'HomeTeamAbbr': 'MIL',
    'GameDate': '2017-05-09',
    'AwayTeamID': '113'
}, {
    'HomeTeamCity': 'Milwaukee',
    'Date/TimeofUpdate:2017-05-075:13:51PM': '',
    'HomeTeamName': 'Brewers',
    'HomeTeamID': '134',
    'AwayTeamName': 'Red Sox',
    'AwayTeamAbbr': 'BOS',
    'GameTime': '8:10PM',
    'AwayTeamCity': 'Boston',
    'HomeTeamAbbr': 'MIL',
    'GameDate': '2017-05-10',
    'AwayTeamID': '113'
}]
```

I keep getting an error that this type cannot be iterated, though when I simply manipulate this output in python via loops and print there are no issues iterating through.

Comment: Is this a template language? If so, which one?

Comment: It would appear you're actually doing `rows = today_games` somewhere, without calling the function. Please double check your code.